# Как правильно перечислить массив

Tags: php

есть такой массив

```
array(9) { 
[0]=> array(2) { 
    ["name"]=> string(28) "Маша" ["Id"]=> float(94224) }
[1]=> array(2) { 
    ["name"]=> string(20) "Даша" ["Id"]=> float(472326) } 
[2]=> array(2) { 
    ["name"]=> string(57) "Глаша" ["Id"]=> float(466360) }
[3]=> array(2) { 
    ["name"]=> string(17) "Петя" ["Id"]=> float(399155) }
[4]=> array(2) { 
    ["name"]=> string(71) "Дима" ["Id"]=> float(229633) }
[5]=> array(2) {
    ["name"]=> string(20) "Вася" ["Id"]=> float(948870) }
[6]=> array(2) {
    ["name"]=> string(18) "Нашествие" ["Id"]=> float(395979) } 
[7]=> array(2) { 
    ["name"]=> string(49) "Малкольм в центре внимания" ["Id"]=> float(255370) }
[8]=> array(2) { 
    ["name"]=> string(27) "Моя жена и дети" ["Id"]=> float(416846) }
    }
```

как мне циклом пройти массив и получить значения ключей id

Comment: какая версия php ?

Comment: по-моему с 5.6 работает array_column

Comment: @splash58 спасибо но только  с версии 5.6  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php оформляйте ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

начиная с версии 5.6  вы можете воспользоваться функцией array_column :

```
array_column($array, 'id');
```

a в более ранних версиях можно использовать array_map :

```
array_map(function($i) { return $i['id']; }, $array);
```